# On duplicate key update not working

Tags: php, mysql

I try to use  **on duplicate key update** in my query but it still duplicate some value.

My query is like this:

```
 $insert=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into tbl_staffdistribution(db_user,db_name,db_responsible,db_date)values('$user','$name','$responsible','$formatteddatetimein') on duplicate key update db_user='$user',db_name='$name',db_responsible='$responsible',db_date='$formatteddatetimein'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

I have **db_id** in my database is a primary key auto increment.

The problem is that I have a duplicate value in my database and that should not happen How can I solve this problem ??

Comment: have you created particular column to unique key

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal i have only the db_id primary and auto increment nothing else

Comment: so on which column basis you are distinguish unique data..you have to create an unique column so that you can identify data

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Thank you i understand why it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this. you should be having a `unique key` within  your table so that you can use it for `on duplicate key update` as such. The unique key can be your primary or some other field from your table. You can do something like this within your query:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE someID = VALUES(someID)
```

A clear cut explanation from [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).